# Regex Help, Parse into NameValueCollection

Tags: .net, regex, string, parsing, namevaluecollection

I'm having an issue with `RegEx`.  I receive a string that needs to be parsed into a `NameValueCollection`.  ParseQueryString doesn't work because (1) the string is space delimited and (2) the values can contain spaces.  I have no control over the input.

Example String:

```
-AppCode='MyApplication' -AppVers='V-2016.0 Debug' -MachUuid='2C850880-34FD-12F3-A06B-7336B0C4BC55' -MachName='ABEZG-F05507' -Language=2055
```

String values that can contain spaces or hyphens are enclosed in single quotes. Integer values are not enclosed in quotes.

I've tried:

- `[\w\-]+=[\w\s\']+(?![\w\-]+=[\w\s\'\-])`

but this doesn't allow for hyphens in the value

- `[\w\-]+=[\w\s\'\-]+(?![\w\-]+=[\w\s\'\-])`

This does, but it overruns the space character.

Ideal output would be:

```
-AppCode MyApplication
-AppVers V-2016.0 Debug
-MachUuid 2C850880-34FD-12F3-A06B-7336B0C4BC55
-MachName ABEZG-F05507
-Language 2055
```

Unfortunately after all these years I still can't figure out `RegEx`.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<name>[\w-]+)=(?:'(?<value>[^']*)'|(?<value>\S+))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3cname%3e%5b%5cw-%5d%2b)%3d(%3f%3a%27(%3f%3cvalue%3e%5b%5e%27%5d*)%27%7c(%3f%3cvalue%3e%5cS%2b))&i=-AppCode%3d%27MyApplication%27+-AppVers%3d%27V-2016.0+Debug%27+-MachUuid%3d%272C850880-34FD-12F3-A06B-7336B0C4BC55%27+-MachName%3d%27ABEZG-F05507%27+-Language%3d2055)

The `([\w-]+)` captures into Group named "name" word and hyphen characters. The `(?:'(?<value>[^']*)'|(?<value>\S+))` will match either single quoted values (`'[^']*'`) of non-whitespaces (`\S+`) but will place into Group with name "value" only the non-whitespaces or the contents inside the `'...'` excluding the quotes themselves.

Sample [C# demo](http://ideone.com/IsNQmH):

```
var str = "-AppCode='MyApplication' -AppVers='V-2016.0 Debug' -MachUuid='2C850880-34FD-12F3-A06B-7336B0C4BC55' -MachName='ABEZG-F05507' -Language=2055";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<name>[\w-]+)=(?:'(?<value>[^']*)'|(?<value>\S+))")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Groups["name"].Value, p=> p.Groups["value"].Value );
foreach (var p in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.Key + ": " + p.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
-AppCode: MyApplication
-AppVers: V-2016.0 Debug
-MachUuid: 2C850880-34FD-12F3-A06B-7336B0C4BC55
-MachName: ABEZG-F05507
-Language: 2055
```

Comment: Phenomenal answer speed!  Thanks!  Another thing, I didn't realize there was a specific .Net "flavor" of RegEx.  I had to modify your answer to ([\w-]+)=(?:'([^']*)'|(\S+)) in order for it to work in .Net.  Next time I'll make that clear in the question.

Comment: It is not a problem: use *named capture groups* in .NET. I will modify the answer.

Comment: I fully re-vamped the answer for .NET. Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).